# How do I create a TOP 10 DESENRANK per Axis in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I need to make a chart using the TOP 10 customers for the annual sales value.

In my table I have:

```
Axis -x: Year
Axis-y: Total Sales
Color: Name_Client
```

In my table I have more than 200 client names and 5 years (2012 a 2017), and I also need those who stay above the TOP 10, stay in a column called "Others".

I've seen some tutorials here, but I did not get the result. The latter was to apply the Desenrank formula, but not breakage per year.

`If (DenseRank (Sum ([totalsales]) OVER ([name_client]), "desc") <= 10, [name_client], "Others")`

Has anyone had this experience?

Comment: @V.Souza- Could you post sample data?

Comment: you need to add `[year]` as group by to both sum and rank: `If (DenseRank (Sum ([totalsales]) OVER ([name_client],[year]), "desc",[year]) <= 10, [name_client], "Others")`. Note this will work correctly only if no two companies has the same `sum` in top 10, Otherwise you need to use a more complicated expression.

Comment: Hi, the function works if I do not use a filter, but when I apply a filter (state, city, genre, etc ...) the function does not perform rank. In most cases it puts everything into "Others".Do I need to apply another parameter or do it differently?

Comment: In some cases I noticed that the number repeats, but in others it does not. What formula do I have to apply in this case with the name repeated?